# rotating a line in context?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, cgcontext

I have drawn 2 line in draw rect.but  i want to rotate a first line in an angle?

```
    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 65, 40);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,165, 40);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    CGContextBeginPath(context);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 10.0);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,[UIColor blackColor].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 85, 80);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 185, 80);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
    CGContextClosePath(context);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation.

```
    CGAffineTransform rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(theAngle);
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, rotation);
```

Good Luck